# If statement not working - keeps going to else statement even when if condition is matched

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x

This is what I've got right now in Python

```
import sys
num = input('Give me a four digit number.')
a = num[0]
b = num[1]
c = num[2]
d = num[3]

if d == 0:
    print(c + b + a)
else:
    print(d + c + b + a)
```

but when I input, say, 1230, it'll return 0321 back to me.
Does any one know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i try your code the first thing that occur is a `TypeError` due to the evaluation of the input, so it's casted to type `int`. But I assume you used quotes so this was not the problem.

The problem is, as you may notice, the type of the given input. In Python 2.X there was `raw_input`, which just returned the input string without evaluating it.
The answer is:

```
print(c+b+a if d=='0' else d+c+b+a)

# or

if d == '0':
    print(c + b + a)
else:
    print(d + c + b + a)
```